# implementing server-side dataTable using SQL Server 2012 | PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, datatable, sqlsrv

I tried to search it for a week now, I did research here, check for guides in YouTube, and read guides in *datatables.net*, but still, I'm having problems implementing **Server-Side dataTable using SQL Server 2012**.

Can you guys please provide me with a step-by-step guide on how to implement it?

I stumble across this guide https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/join.html, and there's so many things in there that I don't understand.

If you guys could please simplify this? or convert this into a more readable code for newbies of this field, like me? Like for example.

*index.php* will consist of the following codes.

```
//codes goes here.
```

*conn.php* will consist of the following codes.

```
//codes goes here.
```

*ajax.php* will consist of the following codes.

```
//codes goes here.
```

and so on.. Or a sample script with like 2-3 columns.

I currently have a working code that only populates dataTable when the script is being called. I used AJAX and Javascript on it as well. I'm using *sqlsrv* as my connection for SQL Server 2012

> It would lessen my coding time for more than **50%** if I could have a guide in implementing Server-Side dataTable using SQL Server 2012 as most of my pages are dataTable-reliant.

Like for this line in *Server Script*

```
// DataTables PHP library
include( "../../php/DataTables.php" );
```

What is DataTables.php supposed to have inside? SQL connection? What does the guide mean by // DataTables PHP library? Where can I find *join.php* in `ajax: "../php/join.php",`

It would be extremely great if you guys could share in a more understandable way the guide above.

Thank you.

EDIT: This is my working **Client-Side dataTable**

This is my *conn.php*

```
<?php
$serverName = "XXXX\XXXX";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"XXXX, "UID"=>"XXXX", "PWD"=>"XXXX",'ReturnDatesAsStrings'=>true, "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
}else{
     echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
?>
```

This is my *account_type.php*

```
              <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <th>Series No.</th>
                  <th>Account Type</th>
                  <th>Tools</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <?php
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM accounttype";
                    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, array(), array("Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET));
                    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                      echo "
                        <tr>
                        <td>".$row['seriesno']."</td>
                          <td>".$row['accounttype']."</td>
                          <td>
                            <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm edit btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm delete btn-flat' data-id='".$row['seriesno']."'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      ";
                    }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
```

This is my script

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on('click', '.edit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#edit').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });

  $("body").on('click', '.delete', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#delete').modal('show');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    getRow(id);
  });
});
```

Please take a look at my code for Server Side (Using PHP Editor).

This is my **config.php** https://anotepad.com/notes/esq7p2

This is my **staff.php** https://anotepad.com/notes/smsiqy

This is my **test.php** https://anotepad.com/notes/8ff7qg

This is the data being displayed when I open **staff.php** https://anotepad.com/notes/exem84

Comment: @LucasTaulealea, Apologies for this matter, it's just that Server-Side dataTable is so new to me, I often just call SQL script and display it in my page.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally submitted comment early. You need to school up on how PHP & SQL.Start here:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp
Once you understand that you can plug it into datatables without ajax.
Once you understand that concept, you can work on getting AJAX included.
Each of these topics are pretty indepth, you're asking broad questions

Comment: @LucasTaulealea no worries. I understand how mysql works, as this is what I've been using for the past couple of years, its this SQL SERVER 2012 that's giving me a hard time. Specially with this guide https://editor.datatables.net/examples/simple/join.html, I don't understand any of this as it is not readable for newbies into this field like me.

Comment: This isn't anything to do with SQL server. The syntax between MySQL and MSSQL is not the issue here. Have you got a working example of datatables working? From your own data? Do you specifically need the datatables ajax call? Or can you live with it just loading your data?

Comment: @LucasTaulealea Sorry for the late reply, the past 2 days have been busy, please see my edit.

Comment: Ok, do you understand how ajax works?

Comment: @LucasTaulealea, yes, I do, it's the configuration for Server Side that I cant work out. I didn't include my dataTable in that post since I deemed it's not necessary. The script that I posted is for my modal, in which I did not included as well.

Comment: Where can I find join.php in ajax: "../php/join.php",

You have to make this file yourself. It will contain a php sql query which will return data in the format as shown in the guide. Does that make sense?

Comment: @LucasTaulealea, please check my new edit. I added some notepads in there. Those are the codes that I am currently working on using the guides from dataTable. When I open *staff.php*, the data is there and its being loaded, but when I open *test.php*, it's not being loaded in the database.

Comment: what does a POSTMAN response look like if you ping staff.php?

Comment: @LucasTaulealea I'm currently testing in in XAMPP

Comment: You can still use postman, its just a tool for testing post requests. You need to make the staff.php file return a data format matching that required by datatables. So you should be testing what response is being sent. Postman will do that for you.

Comment: @LucasTaulealea okay. I'll check it out. I'll get back to you asap. Thank you.